# Is there a way to describe props on react component so that the user can have better autcomplete?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code

I use vscode.

When I'm using component I'd like there to be autocomplete that a) suggest possible props. b) shows small description what the prop is for just as you'd get when writing a function.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use [JSDoc format](https://devdocs.io/jsdoc/about-getting-started) comments on your props types and VSCode should fill in the rest.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, i use ES7 React/Redux/GraphQL/React-Native snippets and  Prettier - Code formatter

Comment: Please show an example in your answer.  It will help folks who come by this question in the future.